# Symfony 2 and Multiple databases with config.yml settings

Tags: doctrine-orm, schema, symfony-2.3, multiple-databases

I have a problem in Symfony 2.3 specifically, where I need to generate schema and update it, access tables in 2 differents databases. Both are in MySQL.
[How to Work with multiple Entity Managers and Connections](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) doesn't fix to the scenario, even it's recommended in some articles around.

### Errors:

[RuntimeException]
  Bundle "XyzBundle" does not contain any mapped entities.

### Commands:

- doctrine:generate entities XyzBundle --no-backup
- doctrine:schema:update --force --em=payment

### #/app/config/config.yml

```
doctrine:
  #... connections (default, payment, etc.)
  orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                MyBundle: ~           
        payment:
            connection: payment
            mappings:
                ZkPaymentBundle: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I found these excellent articles, where many configurations forms are mentioned.

[Doctrine ORM](https://test-sf-doc-es.readthedocs.org/en/latest/book/doctrine/orm.html#mapping-configuration)

[Install Gedmo Doctrine2 extensions in Symfony2](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/symfony2.md)

Even when the bundle isn't in 'vendor/' dir, it was necessary assume that was an external one.

### #/app/config/config.yml

```
        payment:
            connection: payment
            mappings:
                XyzBundle:
                    type: annotation
                    prefix: Xyz\XyzBundle\Entity
                    dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Xyz/XyzBundle/Entity"
```

### Commands

- doctrine:generate:entities Xyz/XyzBundle/Entity --no-backup
- doctrine:schema:update --force --em=payment

I hope it saves a lot of wasted time.